# Cant verify CSRF token authenticity while creating json and html response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am using my sessions controller to authenticate user through an API call or on the rails web app. The code works fine for the web app but for the api call I a getting cant verify CSRF token. I have set the
`protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` as null in my applications controller, but still getting this error. Any idea whats missing?

```
class Drivers::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  after_filter :set_csrf_headers, only: [:create, :destroy]
  respond_to :json, :html
  def create
    password = params[:driver][:password]
    email = params[:driver][:email]
    driver = email.present? && Driver.find_by(email: email)
    if driver.valid_password? password
      sign_in driver, store: true
      driver.reset_authentication_token!
      driver.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to drivers_path}
      format.json { render json: JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(driver.to_json)), status: 200 }
    end

      #render json: driver, status: 200
    else
      render json: { errors: "Invalid email or password" }, status: 422
    end
  end
  protected
  def set_csrf_headers
    cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token if protect_against_forgery?  
  end
end
```

Here is the error:

```
Started POST "/drivers/login.json?email=driver@test.com&password=[FILTERED]" for ::1 at 2016-08-27 08:11:03 -0400
Processing by Drivers::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"apidriver@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My Applications controller file

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    #skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    before_filter :set_paper_trail_whodunnit
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    respond_to :html, :json



  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  #protect_from_forgery with: :exception



  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| 
      u.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :description) 
    }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)  { |u| 
      u.permit(:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name) 
  }
  end
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      if current_driver
        drivers_path #your path
      end
      if current_user
        new_booking_path
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you just getting the warning "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" but request serves the correct JSON response?

Comment: @kiddorails I have updated my question with the error message.

Comment: Can you show ApplicationController as well? Also, to debug - can you check if removing protect_from_forgery line altogether temporarily fixes your issue?

Comment: I tried removing the line, it did gave me the same error. I have updated the description with my applications controller file.